# Search CSV file with python with if statements

Tags: python

I've been trying to search my csv file in python which works so that it outputs the cost of each item etc. But if a wrong GTIN code is input i need it to say it can't find the product. Help is needed. Many Thanks in advance

```
import csv

with open('PriceList.csv') as csvfile:
readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
GTINcode = []
Products = []
Quantitys = []
PricePu = []
Totals = []
for row in readCSV:
    Product = row[1]
    GTIN = row[0]
    Quantity = row[2]
    Total = row[4]
    Price = row[3]

    GTINcode.append(GTIN)
    Products.append(Product)
    Quantitys.append(Quantity)
    Totals.append(Total)
    PricePu.append(Price)
whatColor = input('Enter the GTIN code of the product you wish:')
coldex = GTINcode.index(whatColor)
theDate = Products[coldex]
info = Quantitys[coldex]
ppi = PricePu[coldex]
tts = Totals[coldex]

print('Your GTIN code of:',whatColor,'is',theDate,"We have",info,"left in      stock. The price for each item is",ppi,"and the total cost of this would be",tts)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a [try and except](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#try)  if the value looked for does not exist. As well as a while loop to keep on trying!

```
import csv

with open('PriceList.csv') as csvfile:
readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
GTINcode = []
Products = []
Quantitys = []
PricePu = []
Totals = []
for row in readCSV:
    Product = row[1]
    GTIN = row[0]
    Quantity = row[2]
    Total = row[4]
    Price = row[3]

    GTINcode.append(GTIN)
    Products.append(Product)
    Quantitys.append(Quantity)
    Totals.append(Total)
    PricePu.append(Price)
error = True
while error:
    whatColor = input('Enter the GTIN code of the product you wish:')
    try:
        coldex = GTINcode.index(whatColor)
        error = False
        theDate = Products[coldex]
        info = Quantitys[coldex]
        ppi = PricePu[coldex]
        tts = Totals[coldex]
        print('Your GTIN code of:',whatColor,'is',theDate,"We have",info,"left in      stock. The price for each item is",ppi,"and the total cost of this would be",tts)
    except ValueError:
        print('This is not a valid GTIN code')
```

Comment: This is a great help!!